# Link to content within an accordion from another accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of accordions on my page. I would like to use anchor links to link to a piece of content within another accordion item.

My entire code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/hgfz285d/

As you will see I have 3 Accordions. In accordion 2 I have the content I want to link to wrapped in a `span` with the `ID` of `link1`. In my third accordion I have a link targeting `href="#link1"`. How can I open the targeted accordion and scroll to the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage `click` event on `.expand`, since you already have it working.

```js
var id = jQuery(this).attr('href');
var handle = jQuery(id).closest('.accordian').find('.expand');
handle.click();
```

You also forgot to pass `e` event variable.
[Refactored JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/hgfz285d/2/)

Comment: Sorry, would you mind showing this in context within the code provided?

Comment: Actually I have it working so it goes to the accordian. How can I make it so the accordian opens but goes to the actual element with the id set?

Comment: Managed to do this using scrollTop to the id. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use it after `.accordian` expands, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/hgfz285d/3/